# How to create a Webhook subscription for Azure Event-Grid

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I wanted to prototype a service using azure event-grid and used the following resources to create a custom event-grid topic. I'm trying to add a webbook subscription but there is a mandatory field (system topic name) on the Azure Portal that's not explained in the docs, and cli fails with the error below.

CLI Error:
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 9e13c3c8-4255-4a0c-b5b5-0a9419a385dd. The operation failed due to an internal server error. The initial state of the impacted resources (if any) are restored. Please try again in few minutes. If error still persists, report 698c81db-22a9-4e4a-91cf-55408b2b1486:6/2/2020 8:23:10 AM (UTC) to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket .

Portal Error:
Creation of System Topic has failed with error: System topic creation is not enabled for topic type Microsoft.EventGrid.Topics

Resources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/scripts/event-grid-cli-create-custom-topic
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/scripts/event-grid-cli-subscribe-custom-topic
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to create Event Grid SystemTopic from portal? You need to create Event Grid Topic for Webhook subscription for Azure Event-Grid.

Comment: No, I already created an event grid topic. I'm trying to create a webhook subscription on that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug on the portal. Based on the [System topics in Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/system-topics) document:

*System topic isn't applicable to custom topic scenarios, that is, Event Grid topics and Event Grid domains.*

As a workaround, you can use any value for System Topic Name property to create the Event Subscription via the portal.

The following screen snippet shows a portal notifications during a process of the Event Subscription creating and deploying.

[image]

Comment: I get the error: Creation of System Topic has failed with error: System topic creation is not enabled for topic type Microsoft.EventGrid.Topics when I do that.

Comment: I can see that error, too, but the Event Subscription is created successfully.

Comment: mine has failed. it's probably failed due to the same reason when I tried to create it from azure cli. I believe this issue is specific to me then. I've posted the error message on azure forums as it's suggested, hopefully will get an answer from there. I'll try again later.